# Time formatting with strptime in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to read a `CSV` file, where some columns have date or time values.

I started with this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

timeparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

lap_times = pd.read_csv(
    'data/lap_times.csv',
    parse_dates={'time_datetime': ['time']}, 
    date_parser=timeparse
)
```

But sometimes the row of the column has a format `%M:%S.%f` and sometimes has `%H:%M:%S.%f`. So I got an error.

I thought about creating a function like this, but I can't see how I would pass an argument to the function to do the transformation for each row of the column passed as an argument.

```py
def timeparse_1():
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    finally:
        return datetime.strptime(x, '%M:%S.%f')
```

But I'm getting:

```py
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try `def timeparse_1(x):`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what do when I use: date_parser=timeparse_1("what I do here?") inside pd.read_csv(...)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you post a sample of your `CSV` file, but something like this may work:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['12:34:56', '12:34:56.789']})

df.Time = df.Time.apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f') if len(x) > 8 else dt.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

Which will result in:

```py
>>> df
0   1900-01-01 12:34:56.000
1   1900-01-01 12:34:56.789
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

But there is a better way:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['12:34:56', '12:34:56.789']})

df.Time = df.Time.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Which results in the following:

```py
>>> df
0   2022-11-20 12:34:56.000
1   2022-11-20 12:34:56.789
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Using the day of today to complete the `datetime` object.

Comment: This help me a lot, but when I use o df.info(), this show: 
time 528785 non-null  object. 

It's still Object even though every line are showing datetime.time, when i look individually.

Comment: @AndreLuizMoura, what is your pandas version? Try updating it.